# Double free or corruption when memcpy is used for structure is non-pod type

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management, memory-leaks

Problem statement:
following program is used memcpy for copying struct having non-pod data types, that is causing double free. what is best way to copy this types of structures.

```
Struct config
{
   Vector<int> list;
   Vector<int> listmode;
   Int id;
}

Void config_req(struct config confrcvd)
{
   struct config *config_ptr = new config;

   Memcpy((void*)config_ptr, (void*)&configrcvd; sizeof(struct config));

   Vector<struct config *> 
        configvector = push_back(config_ptr);


//Some operation performed with vector. Delete elements of vector causing double free.

for(auto conf : configvector)
{
   delete conf; //this statement is cause for double free
}
Configvector.clear 
}
```

Comment: you should not use memcpy just do an assignment operator otherwise they may refer to the same memory and then when they go out of scope they will free the same memory.,

Comment: You can't memcpy into a struct that contains non-standard-layout types such as `vector<>`.

Comment: C++ is a *very* different language from C.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule in C++ don't use memcpy on non-POD data types.

A vector is internally allocated on the heap so when you do memcpy you basically copy that memory so both copies will refer and free the same memory

Just do

```
struct config *config_ptr = new config;
*config_ptr = confrcvd;
```

or do

```
 struct config *config_ptr = new config(confrcvd);
```

the second part with the vector seems strange too, write like this instead

```
 vector<struct config *> configvector;
 configvector.push_back(config_ptr);
```

or combine it all since you are anyway copying the parameter skip the new and do:

```
 vector<struct config> configvector;
 configVector.emplace_back(confrcvd);
```

Comment: You cannot use a content-unaware method to copy structured content. A vector could haver the equivalent of "just to the left" and if you just copy it from one place to another, it may no longer make sense because the thing referred to isn't in the same relative location. You can't just assume that the same logical contents will have the same representation  in different areas of memory as no rule requires it to. By applying `memcpy` to structured data, you have no guarantee the copy will make semantic sense.

Comment: @Raghavendra yes,, but the question was about memcpy.